# What learning path I must follow to learn ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I'm an OOP developer mostly on the most popular scripting language for web developments, PHP.

To master my skills as a PHP developer, I separate things as PHP, OOP techinques, Client-side languages as Javascript, AJAX, AJAX libraries, CMS, Frameworks (Zend, Cake, etc)
MySQL in depth, LINUX (mostly as a web developer optical) ...

So what guess now I need some specific guidelines to determine what are the concrete domains that I need to master to become myself a ASP.NET developer and then build on top of that a learning path to follow. (like C#, WebForms, ADO, etc) ...

BEST to all the great developers here in SO.

Demian

Answer (score 3):

- C# or VB.Net (C# is preferable) (including sme general knowledge of the CLR)
- ASP.Net Webforms (or ASP.Net MVC)
- ADO.Net (you should also learn LINQ to SQL or another ORM s.a. NHibernate)
- T-SQL and SQL Server (unless you plan to use another Data Base)
- Basic Windows server knowledge and IIS management
- I assume that you know already everything you need about Client Side development. It is advisable to also learn ASP.Net AJAX and JQuery (it's supported by Visual Studio)
- Web services (or better WCF)
- Depending on how complex your applications are, you should also consider looking at some IoC Container s.a. NInject or more advanced frameworks (Enterprise library, Spring.Net)

You can look up the recommeded readings on amazon to each of these topics.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to build an application from scratch, something inside a problem domain you understand or maybe to rewrite a previous project.

There are some useful links to start:

- [Learn ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/learn/)
- [Good Book/Training Material To Learn ASP.NET 2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466898/good-book-training-material-to-learn-asp-net-2-0)
- [Recommended Topics for “Introduction to .Net” training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650769/recommended-topics-for-introduction-to-net-training)
- [What are your references/recommendation on .NET DVDs, books and online training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135096/what-are-your-references-recommendation-on-net-dvds-books-and-online-training)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [skills measured for Microsoft's certification exam 70-562](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-562#tab2) (Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5, ASP.NET Application Development).  It gives a decent, practical idea of some of the skills used during development.

Answer (score 0):

Add Entity Framework in addition to ADO.Net and Linq to SQL.